# Angularjs: Get $routeprovider template from function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I've been reading some important parts of the docs and I found this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Somewhere in there, it says that the `route>template` property can be either `(String|Function)`.
I guess it should be a function that returns html formed-string. What i want to know is if it is possible to use an `http` request to get the html from the server and also how to write such code.

I know this would make angular request the partial on each navigation, which should be counter productive - but i have my reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess it should be a function that returns html formed-string.

Right, like:

```
templateUrl: function(param) {
   return 'views/' + param.details + '.html' ;
}
```

> What i want to know is if it is possible to use an http request to get the html from the server

No, you cannot do that.

The `config` loads first and you cannot inject `$http` into `config`